# Select from 2 tables (Kohana framework)

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I've got 2 tables with the same datastructure.

Ex:

```
table 1 (id, pay_amount, package, date)
table 2 (id, pay_amount, package, date)
```

How can I get with Kohana framework data from both tables
and sum the results by days?
also how can I substr a string and sum the rest of the string (which is a number? look at the package_credit_ row in the example).

For example if I have this data:

```
Table1: 
(1, 200, "package_credit_300", "12.12.12 12:02:34"), 
(2, 50, "package_credit_50", "12.12.12 15:17:02"), 
(2, 50, "package_credit_50", "13.12.12 16:12:12")

Table2: 
(1, 50, "package_credit_50", "13.12.12 12:02:34"), 
(2, 50, "package_credit_50", "13.12.12 15:17:02"), 
(2, 200, "package_credit_300", "14.12.12 16:12:12")
```

I want to get something liket that:

```
Date: 12.12.12 - Credit: 350 - Paid: 250
Date: 13.12.12 - Credit: 150 - Paid: 150
Date: 14.12.12 - Credit: 300 - Paid: 200
```

Comment: The date is not in mysql date format.

Comment: yeah but its not the values im using its just an example so you can ignore the format :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done using ORM or ActiveRecord in Kohana. You need to execute this custom sql.

```
SELECT Date(t.`date`)                                    AS `Date`, 
       Sum(Cast(Substring(t.`package`, 16) AS UNSIGNED)) AS `Credit`, 
       Sum(t.pay_amount)                                 AS `Paid` 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   table1 
        UNION 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   table2) AS `t` 
GROUP  BY `Date` 
ORDER  BY `Date` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   SELECT Substring(t.`date`,1,8)                        AS dates, 
   Sum(Cast(Substring(t.`package`, 16) AS UNSIGNED)) AS `Credit`, 
   Sum(t.pay_amount)                                 AS `Paid` 
    FROM   (SELECT * 
    FROM   table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   table2) AS `t` 
    GROUP  BY dates 
    ORDER  BY dates ASC
```

[**LOOK DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1807e/15)